# Ruby Array: Is there an easy way to chunk by elements themselves?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I recently do this kind of chunk quite a few, which is to chuck the array by the elements themselves:

```
an_array.chunk{|x| x}
```

Is there any syntactic sugar for this kind of chunk? Thanks :)

For example:

```
an_array=[4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7]
#=> [4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]
```

Then:

```
an_array.chunk{|x| x}
#=> #<Enumerator: ...>

an_array.chunk{|x| x}.to_a
#=> [[4, [4, 4, 4]], [5, [5]], [6, [6, 6, 6, 6]], [7, [7, 7]]]
```

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why would you need to use this in the first place?

Comment: _"I do this a lot"_ – could you give a real-world example?

Comment: @mudasobwa Just algorithm practices for now, thought it would be useful in the future. Thanks for your heads up, you enlightened me with the word :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write this way

```
an_array.chunk(&:itself)
```

Note: [`itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) was introduced in Ruby 2.2

Comment: Although it's actually longer, but it's way more easy to type. Thanks :)